# In phpMyAdmin, how to export a single column from a previous selection

Tags: select, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

I have a database named database1.

I am searching in a specific table, named Product.
In this Product table are various columns such as id_product and Description.
In this Product table, I am searching for the entries containing a specific string in the Description column.

In phpMyAdmin, the above task is easy to do.

Now, after getting the selected results, I would like to export only the id_product column (as a csv file for instance).

Would you know how to export this single column ?

Comment: select just that column and export the result... `SELECT id_product FROM <rest of your query here>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thanks to your advice, I managed to export only the id_product column as a csv file. Is there a way to get all the exported id_products on a single line, each id_product value being separated by a coma ? Thank you again.

Comment: that's what a csv is. Comma Separated Values...

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `SQL` tab and use this query :

   (select column_name from table_name)

[image]

2. Select the rows you want to export

[image]

3. Select the fromat you want

[image]